# CK Editor uploaded images needs to respond as responsive images

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using CK Editor 5 and a Simple upload adapter which works fine. All text and images from the editor is stored into a database when submitted. Also working just fine.

But when I reload and present the data/html it's not behaiving as expect. I need for the images to be responsive if I alter the width of the browser, but the images are quite static.

CK Editor has produced the following HTML (snippet is only the image part)

```
<figure class="image">
<img src="/img/article/160742759333072416.jpg">
</figure>
```

What do I need to do to make CK Editor produce HTML which supports responsive images?

*Note: I am not able to use CK Editors 'Easy Image' Cloud option. I need to use an my owb om prem solution.*

Looking forward to suggestions or pointers...

Answer (score 0):

Blasted. After reading documentation for at last 3 more hours I noticed a CSS mistake I did myself while examining my code.

Bad!

Sorry to disturb you all and happy holiday season to all.